# iOS + OpenCV - Mat memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, opencv, objective-c++

I am using OpenCV 2.2 compiled and built from source for iOS. I used this [blog post](http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en) as a guide.

I have played around with getting some stuff to work like making images grayscale, blurring them and even running FAST. My problem however is that my code is leaking memory and this very quickly causes the app to be killed when run on a device.

From the blog post above I use the code below to turn a UIImage into an IplImage

```
+ (IplImage *)IplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
    // NOTE you SHOULD cvReleaseImage() for the return value when end of the code.
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    IplImage *iplimage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image.size.width, image.size.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(iplimage->imageData, iplimage->width, iplimage->height,
                                                    iplimage->depth, iplimage->widthStep,
                                                    colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    IplImage *ret = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iplimage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvCvtColor(iplimage, ret, CV_RGBA2RGB);

    cvReleaseImage(&iplimage);

    return ret;
}
```

This works fine and does not seem to leak any memory however since I am using OpenCV 2.2 I am trying to use the C++ interface so I created the function below.

```
+ (Mat)MatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    IplImage *iplImage = [self IplImageFromUIImage:image];
    Mat result(iplImage, true);
    cvReleaseImage(&iplImage);
    return result;
}
```

Once I start using this method my app starts leaking and consequently gets killed.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[Classname IplImageFromUIImage:image]` and not `self` since you are using `+`?

Comment: @slf: that call is inside a class method, so `self` refers to the class object, not an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are calling

```
Mat::Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false)
```

With copyData set to `true`, can you be sure that `Mat::release()` is being called?  If your refcount never returns to 0, your destructor never fires leaving you with lots of copies of the image data in ram.

Comment: This was certainly my first thought. After reading the Mat documentation however it suggests that this just handles everything. I only ever have Mat objects on the stack, not the heap so I would have thought the refcount would have gone to zero when they went out of scope. Any suggestions on how to verify what is going on?

Comment: Use instruments with the leak detector, you can see what is leaking and even capture the contents of RAM that leaked while it's running

Comment: I had other errors in my program that were causing memory problems at a higher level. That said I think that this answer was a sufficient response to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the difference between a data provider and a data reference is key; destroying a reference or reassigning the reference to another object does not affect the data stored in the provider, except where the developer of the framework makes it so (such as Apple). OpenCV does not associate a CGImageRef with any of its objects that store image data, per se; therefore, it requires you to destroy the CGImageRef (i.e., dereference its image data object) and then release and deallocate the OpenCV object that stores the image data (cv::Mat).

To ensure you've released the data stored in, say, cv::Mat, just cv::Mat.empty() after releasing and deallocating the object:

Whereas...

```
if (mat.empty())...
```

...returns FALSE, this...

```
mat.deallocate();
mat.release();
```

...will...

```
if (mat.empty())...
```

...return TRUE.